# Need custom data sorter with Bootstrap that puts one value at the very end

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

I'm trying to create a data-sorter function in Javascript that would put one value (Total in my case) at the very last of an HTML table. However, Total is sorted alphabetically instead.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
function methodNameSorter(a, b) {
    // Total must be at very end of the list of methods.
    if (a === "Total" && b === "Total") return 0;
    if (a === "Total") return 1;
    if (b === "Total") return -1;

    var result = a.localeCompare(b);
    return result;
}
```

Here is the HTML that uses the function in the table through Bootstrap:

```
<table id="methods-summary-table" class="table table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="asc">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true" data-sorter="methodNameSorter">Method name</th>
          ...
        </tr>
    ...
    </thead>
...
</table>
```

Here is the sorting order I have with this code, and Total should be at the end but it's not:

```
Login
Logout
Total
Transaction_A
Verify_X
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are 'a' and 'b'? Are they the innerhtml or the element itsself? If they  are the element, you need to use `if (a.innerHTML === 'Total')` instead

Comment: 'a' and 'b' are the strings of the cell. I can confirm this by debugging it in the Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Doublecheck this, becaase your code works on the array `['Login', 'Logout', 'Total', 'Transaction_A', 'Verify_X']`, sorting this with your fn gives me `"Login,Logout,Transaction_A,Verify_X,Total"`

Comment: @Shilly: that's right, there is something wrong with `a` and `b`, they are not the strings I expected to have, they are the HTML contents of the cell (there's a `<a href=.../>` in my case there too). I will see how I can get the string somehow.

`a.innerHTML` returns `undefined` in my case, I can't use this, it seems.

Comment: Hmmm, so we have to go to the parent I guess. Can you update to show what exactly in inside the TH and which nodeName 'a' and 'b' have, so we know how many parent elements up we need to go.

Comment: Here is what the cell looks like: `<td><a href="#total">Total</a></td>`
Right now, according to the debugger, `a` is: `<a href="#total">Total</a>`.
It should be `Total`. It's the same pattern for all values.

Comment: Then `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` should work , strange.

Comment: @Shilly: I have found a solution to my problem, see the answer I just posted. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Total` checks made above work, it's just the arguments, `a` and `b` that were wrong.

The arguments were in this format: `<a href="#total">Total</a>`

Here is the updated Javascript function that deals with the `<a href=...>` tag:

```
function methodNameSorter(a, b) {
    // Keep the method name only (remove the <a href=...></a> tag).
    var method_a = a.split('>')[1].slice(0, -3)
    var method_b = b.split('>')[1].slice(0, -3)

    // Total must be at very end of the list of methods.
    if (method_a === "Total" && method_b === "Total") return 0;
    if (method_a === "Total") return 1;
    if (method_b === "Total") return -1;

    var result = method_a.localeCompare(method_b);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So the answer is that a and b aren't html nodes at all. They are the outerHTML of those nodes instead of the nodes themselves. I hope this is in the bootstrap docs, since after you told me that the debugger says 'a' is `<a href="#total">Total</a>` I wrongly assumed it's the entire node, not the outerHTML.